# How to take a variable inside if else statement in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to take a value inside of if/else statement and send an error message with "that variable" because I don't want any of my inputs to be more than 99 characters.

This is the code:

```
if(empty($x) || empty($y) || empty($z)){

$_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]="You have to fill all the blanks.";
redirect_to("addxyz.php");


} elseif(strlen($x)>99 || strlen($y)>99 || strlen($z)>99){

$_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]="Very Long  Name for /*variable name will be here*/";
redirect_to("addxyz.php");

}  else {/*Rest of the code*/}
```

In the second part when I use strlen function with variables, I need to select one of it with an array or any other way but not using 3 different if/else statement. 
    What would be the best way ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make an array with your three variables and then validate them with a `foreach` loop. Even in the same `foreach` loop you could make the first validation you have:

```
foreach(array($x, $y, $z) as $values) {//---> the $values variable represents each of your '$x, $y, $z' variables in the loop.
    if (empty($values)) {
        $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]="You have to fill all the blanks.";
        redirect_to("addxyz.php");

    } else if (strlen($values) > 99) {
        $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]="Very Long  Name for $values";//---> This will notify the first value that fails the validation.
        redirect_to("addxyz.php");
    }
}
```

If more than one value fails the validation (for example `$x` and `$z`) and you want to notify them all, you could save the `$values` value in an array and then show it. Something like this:

```
$strlenErrors = array();
foreach(array($x, $y, $z) as $values) {
    if (strlen($values) > 99) {
        $strlenErrors[] = $values;
    }
}

if (!empty($strlenErrors)) {
    $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]="Very Long  Name for: ".implode(", ", $strlenErrors);//---> This will divide and print the '$strlenErrors' array by commas.
    redirect_to("addxyz.php");
}
```

Comment: probably what he wants just going to point out that this will redirect on the first variable > than 99, if you want to explicitly check all 3 regardless of one matching, it will have to be done differently.

Comment: I see, well due to the second part of the question, I understood that the OP wants to make the same `strlen` validation in a shorter way. Maybe we need to ask for more information?

Comment: Hi Julian,
Where I wrote, /*variable name will be here*/

 I want to say "Very long name for '$x'" for example. Depending on which one is bigger than 99. Thanks.